# Top level heading in the `org-mode` agenda

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to show top level heading ("project" heading) in the agenda?

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("g" todo "WAITING" nil)
("n" todo "NEXT" nil)
("i" todo "IN-PROGRESS" nil)
("w" "Agenda + In-progress + Next Actions @work"
 ((agenda) (todo "IN-PROGRESS") (todo "NEXT"))
 ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("+@work"))))
("d" "Agenda + In-progress + Next Actions"
 ((agenda) (todo "IN-PROGRESS") (todo "NEXT")))))
```

Projects file is part of Getting Things Done and I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/gtd/inbox.org"
                     "~/Dropbox/gtd/projects.org"
                     "~/Dropbox/gtd/tickler.org"))
```

Projects file contains headings for each project and subtrees of TODO lists. I guess I can just add a tag to each heading and filter by that tag but each heading will just appear as a TODO entry rather than a heading in the agenda.

Comment: The three main choices are `org-search-view`, `org-tags-view`, and `org-agenda-list`.  Here is a link to the org-mode manual regarding advanced searching:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html .  It is unclear from the question whether the `project` is defined in your `org-todo-keywords`, and it is unknown whether you tried to search for that keyword; or, whether your have a particular tag in the heading containing your `project` that you could search for ...; or, ....  At the present, we really have no idea what the `project` is in the context of this question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The level of a heading is stored in the special `LEVEL` property.  You can search for like any other property.  To restrict to a particular file, you can locally set `org-agenda-files` for that agenda command.  For example:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("1" "Level 1 project headings" 
     tags-todo 
     "LEVEL=1"
     ((org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/gtd/projects.org")))
   )))
```